# I want to use rx.js to merge multiple data sources and support adding and deleting data sources

Tags: rxjs

I have multiple data sources, and they're hot Observable（BehaviorSubject）

```
const data1$ = new BehaviorSubject({key: 'a', value: 1})
const data2$ = new BehaviorSubject({key: 'b', value: 2})
const data3$ = new BehaviorSubject({key: 'c', value: 3})
```

And I have a root that aggregates other data sources

```
const root$ = new BehaviorSubject({ field: {/* Stores the values of other data sources*/ } })
```

The idea is that when I subscribe to root$, I get an aggregation of their data, and when dataX$ is updated(next), I get an aggregation of the updates.

Also, I would like to receive updates when adding/deleting data sources.

This is my code so far, and I can't think of a way to implement it.

```
const a1$ = new BehaviorSubject({key: 'a', value: 1})
const a2$ = new BehaviorSubject({key: 'b', value: 2})
const trunk$ = new BehaviorSubject([a1$, a2$])

function add(dataSourch) {
  trunk$.next([...trunk$.getValue(), dataSourch])
}
function remove(key) {
  const dataArr = trunk$.getValue()
  const newArr = dataArr.filter((sourch) => sourch.key !== key)
  trunk$.next([...newArr])
}
```

————————————————————————————————————

**At present: my problem is to add a new data source in the following code, and the final data source will trigger multiple updates**

I added additional information and code on this issue

I have some basic data sources, which are subscribed by different roles and modified by different roles.
At the same time, I have a aggregation data source, which aggregates the data of the basic data source to a field (the aggregation data source itself has other data),
and is subscribed by some roles.
And the basic data source management module supports adding and deleting data sources.
[image]

```
const data1$ = new BehaviorSubject({key: 'a', value: 1})
const data2$ = new BehaviorSubject({key: 'b', value: 1})
const data3$ = new BehaviorSubject({key: 'c', value: 1})
const data4$ = new BehaviorSubject({key: 'd', value: 1})

const addSourch = (curr: any) => (prev: any) => ([curr, ...prev])
const addSourch$ = new Subject()
const deleteSourchByOb = (curr: any) => (arr: any) => {
  const newArr = arr.filter((ele: any) => ele !== curr)
  return newArr
} 
const deleteSourchByOb$ = new Subject()
const deleteAll = () => (prev: any) => ([])
const deleteAll$ = new Subject()

const sourch$ = new BehaviorSubject([data1$, data2$, data3$])


const root$ = merge(
  sourch$.pipe(map(arr => (curr: any) => [...arr, ...curr])),
  addSourch$.pipe(map(addSourch)),
  deleteSourchByOb$.pipe(map(deleteSourchByOb)),
  deleteAll$.pipe(map(deleteAll))
).pipe(
  scan((state, fn: Function) => fn(state), [])
) 

const thunk$ = new BehaviorSubject({ field: { }})

const root2$= root$.pipe(
  mergeMap(arr => merge(...arr)),
  map((v: any) => (curr: any) => {
    const obj = cloneDeep(curr)
    obj[v.key] = v
    return obj
  })
).pipe(
  scan((state, fn) => fn(state), {})
)

const final$ = combineLatest([root2$, thunk$]).pipe(
  map((arr) => {
    arr[1].field = arr[0]
    return arr[1]
  }) 
)
final$.subscribe(console.log)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this behavior by using the [scan](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/scan) operator.

```js
const { BehaviorSubject, Subject, merge } = rxjs;
const { map, scan } = rxjs.operators;

// Your functions that mutate your state/data aggregation
const add = (data) => (state) => ([...state, data]);
const deleteAll = () => (state) => ([]);

const data1$ = new BehaviorSubject({key: 'a', value: 1})
const data2$ = new BehaviorSubject({key: 'b', value: 2})
const data3$ = new BehaviorSubject({key: 'c', value: 3})

// Observable that represents all add events
const add$ = merge(data1$, data2$, data3$)
// Observable that represents all deleteAll events
const deleteAll$ = new Subject();

const data$ = merge(
  // Applies the first (outer) mutate function to your event observables
  add$.pipe(map(add)),
  deleteAll$.pipe(map(deleteAll))
).pipe(
  // Applies the second (inner) mutate function to finally mutate and return your updated state
  scan((state, fn) => fn(state), [])
)

data$.subscribe(console.log)

// Sample further events
data1$.next({key: 'd', value: 4})
deleteAll$.next();
data1$.next({key: 'e', value: 5})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

If you need any more details, ask for it in the comments and I try to add them to the answer.
FYI: For the sake of the main reason for your question (mutate state over time in rxjs) I did not implement a remove function as you did in your question. You can easily adapt this function to the given `add` and `deleteAll` functions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It brings me a solution.

Now, I have updated my problem and code. In the code, the new data source will trigger four updates. Is there any way to trigger only once.

Comment: Well can you just ask one question after one. You had a specific question, and the answer did fit. If new problems arrive, please ask a new question. Can you please revert to your old question. If you want you can post your new question under my comment and I will have a look at it. Also keep in mind, if the answer worked for your question you have the opportunity to upvote a answer and/or give it a green check.

Comment: As it might answers your question (but a detailed one you get when you ask a new question) - You can next observables into observables. This way you could just next new `dataN$` into one `data$` observable and "unbox" it wherever you need it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I know how to ask questions here now.